# How can I have a python module run asynchronously and recieve calls from other modules?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, process

So I'm currently working on adding a recommendation engine to a Django project and need to do some heavy processing (in an external module) for one of my view functions. This significantly slows down page load time because I have to load in some data, transform it, perform my calculations based on parameters sent by the request, and then return the suggestions to the view. This has to be done every time the view is loaded.

I was wondering if there was some way I could have the recommender module load and transform the data in memory, and then wait for parameters to be sent from the view, have calculations run on those parameters and then send it back to the view.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You basically need a listener on the view, that can receive a message from your external module. Upon completion, let the external module set a flag somewhere independently, like a database field. Your view can keep polling the database periodically to find out if the backend processing is complete.

Comment: This seems like it might be overkill because the actual processing itself is the least computationally intensive part of this process. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Ahh - so that is the specialized case where my idea would fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) is a task queue that reeally excels at this sort of thing.

It would allow you to do something like:

1. user makes request to view
2. view starts an async task that does the heavy lifting, then returns to the user immediately
3. you can poll from javascript to see if your task is done and load the results when it is

Might not quite be the flow you're looking for but celery is definitetly worth checking out
Celery has a great [django package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery/) too, extremely easy to use

*Rereading your question*, i think it would also be possible to create a local webservice around your recommendation engine.  On startup it can load all the data into memory, then you can just make requests to it from your django app?

Comment: The webservice idea sounds good but I don't know if I want to go that route. I was hoping there would be some sort of message passing functionality that I could use for this. Thanks anyway

Comment: I decided to go with the webservice implementation. For anyone else who might run into this problem, it's fairly simple to create a simple server-client relationship xmlrpc server. I had to do minimal modification to the example provided in the python docs for xmlrpclib. 
Just make sure that the view(the client) has its code in a try: except clause. You don't want your whole page going down due to a timeout or socket error.